# Get rid of comma between outputting objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is my code for outputting alerts as they pertain to national parks. Everything is fine except I am getting a comma in between the objects, and I don't know how to fix it. 
Here is my code for outputting the national parks and alerts:

```
const alertEndpoint = ('https://api.nps.gov/api/v1/alerts?limit=400&api_key=' + apikey);
const parkEndpoint = ('https://api.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?limit=500&api_key=' + apikey);

getParkData();

async function getParkData() {


const [parkAlerts, parkInfo] = await Promise.all([fetch(alertEndpoint), fetch(parkEndpoint)]);

const alertResults = await parkAlerts.json();
const parkResults=  await parkInfo.json();

const alertsData = alertResults.data;
const parkData = parkResults.data;

alertsFilter(alertsData, parkData);

}

  function alertsFilter(alertsData, parkData) {

const filteredAlerts = alertsData.filter(function (onlyAlerts) {
    return onlyAlerts.category.toLowerCase() === "park closure" || 
 onlyAlerts.category.toLowerCase() === "caution";


});
parksFilter(parkData, filteredAlerts);



 }

 function parksFilter(parkData, filteredAlerts) {
const filteredParks = parkData.filter(function (onlyNatParks) {
    return onlyNatParks.designation.toLowerCase().includes( "national park");

});
joinParksToAlerts(filteredParks, filteredAlerts);
 }

 function joinParksToAlerts(filteredParks, filteredAlerts) {

const parksJoinedWithAlerts = filteredParks.map(park => {
    park.alerts = filteredAlerts.filter(alert => alert.parkCode === 
 park.parkCode);
    return park}).map(park =>{
    park.alerts = park.alerts.map(alert => alert.description).join(' 
 <br> - ');
    return park

});

 displayAlerts(parksJoinedWithAlerts);

 function joinParksToAlerts(filteredParks, filteredAlerts) {

    const parksJoinedWithAlerts = filteredParks.map(park => {
        park.alerts = filteredAlerts.filter(alert => alert.parkCode ===
            park.parkCode);
        return park
    }).map(park => {
            park.alerts = park.alerts.map(alert => alert.description).join('  <
                br > -');
                return park

            });

        displayAlerts(parksJoinedWithAlerts); console.log(parksJoinedWithAlerts);

    }

    function displayAlerts(parksJoinedWithAlerts) {

        const natParkDiv = document.querySelector('.nationalparks');
        console.table(parksJoinedWithAlerts);



        const displayEverything = parksJoinedWithAlerts.map(parkAndAlerts => {
            const parkName = parkAndAlerts.fullName;
            const stateName = parkAndAlerts.states;
            const alerts = parkAndAlerts.alerts;
            return `
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="park">${parkName}, ${stateName}<br></span>
        <span class="alerts">${alerts}</span>
    </div>
    `

        });
        console.log(displayEverything);

        natParkDiv.innerHTML = displayEverything;
    }
```

and here is the output:

Acadia National Park, ME

Carriage Road access between intersections 10 and 14, along the west side of Jordan Pond, will be closed 6:30 am to 4 pm Oct 23-24 for culvert replacement.

,

Arches National Park, UT

,

Badlands National Park, SD

The Ben Reifel Visitor Center will be without power from 10am to 2pm October 10 & 11. Information may still be obtained at the visitor center. Restrooms, exhibits, movie and bookstore will not be available. Restrooms available at the Cedar Pass Lodge.

,

Big Bend National Park, TX

Due to increased bear activity the Lost Mine Trail area will be closed as of October 12, 2018. The trail, trailhead, parking area, and north facing slope of Casa Grande Peak will be closed until further notice. All other trails remain open at this time.

,

Comment: You can use _reduce()_ to join the array elements together.

Comment: When you force an array into a string context, the elements are implicitly joined using a comma. If you don’t want that, then join them together with the separator of your choice (which in this case would be an empty string), and assign the result of that as innerHTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @MarioSantini - You *can*, but the idiomatic way to do it would be `join`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder of course, my intent was to add a bit of content to push further the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

`park.alerts` and such are *arrays*. You're outputting them by implicitly converting them to string, which calls `join` with no arguments, which defaults to joining the array with commas. To make that not happen, call `join` with an empty string:

```
return `
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="park">${parkName}, ${stateName}<br></span>
    <span class="alerts">${alerts.join()}</span>
</div>
`;
```

Note the change on `alerts`.

---

Side note: In a couple of places you're using text from the objects (from `description`, for instance) directly as HTML. That's insecure, and also problematic from a formatting perspective. You need to at least change `<` to `&lt;` and `&` to `&amp;` when embedding arbitrary unknown text in HTML.

Comment: it's telling me that alerts.join() is not a function after using ${alerts.join()}

Comment: @ScottCaudle - The code in the question is **very** hard to read, but as far as I can tell, `alerts` will be an array and thus will definitely have `join` (it also matches your symptom -- the commas -- perfectly).  Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).